How to define ammunition capacity
I work on a space combat/exploration game, and I got to a point where I require external opinions.
The setup is this: A space ship can have 2-4 weapons, each weapon can have 2-4 ammo types. Ammo types can be switched in combat. The fixed concept is that the player goes "out" and "returns", whereas the time a player can go out is significant (how far he gets, how much he can do in one "session"), and ammo is one resource of multiple that can "run out." Via customization the player can influence that. Ammunition are not items in an inventory, they are a resource like health that start at 100% and might get a bar in the UI. "Ammo types" (for a lack of a better name) can be imagined as devices that modify the incoming or outgoing projectiles of a weapon (longer range, higher damage, lower consumption, higher armor penetration, etc). Weapons have specific purposes, for example turrets are good against small craft, frontal cannons are good against bigger craft and structures, missiles are good against everything but consume a lot of ammo (space/capacity).
Weapons can be activated and fire on their own, targets can also be selected. Turrets behave differently, when activated they automatically acquire targets and prefer split fire, but they can have focus fire targets. The game's focus is about fighting, gathering loot, exploration, mining resources, crafting, upgrading/building stations, trading, transportation. Combat is a common occurrence and every player is capable to fight, and enemies generally come in waves, however avoiding combat, fleeing and trying to survive are part of it too.
There are 3 options how ammo capacity can limit:

Ammo Capacity is global for the ship, and all weapons consume it like a resource. Some weapons consume more or less, some ammo types consume more or less.
Ammo Capacity is bound to each weapon, and the player has to customize how much ammo a weapon gets. Imagine you have 10 boxes of ammo for 2 weapons, weapon 1 gets 6 boxes, weapon 2 gets 4 boxes. Each box contains ammo and quantity appropriate for the weapon they are used for.
Ammo Capacity is bound to each ammo type. This is the realistic version, where each ammo type appropriately has as much as is carried. The player has to customize this, which means splitting up 'x' boxes of ammo to 'y' weapons times 'z' ammo types.

Note that ammo being a limiting resource is essential, and that realism is not important. Game-play is the highest focus, where events like "running out of ammo" matter. There should be sufficient customization options available for the player. Ammo is meant to be a limited resource, should last for multiple combat situations, recharges when home, and its capacity being subject to customization.
The question is this: What are the cons and pros of these 3 options? I am also open for opinions and suggestions.

Not sure this question can be answered objectively. The "best" system depends entirely on what you want to achieve with the game mechanic. That being said I created a small shoot-em-up space game where I did a combo of #1 and #2, the ship type determined the max ammo of all weapons combined and then the player had to allocate ammo to each weapon from that maximum (e.g. Burst Laser gets 50%, Missile Launcher gets 10%, Point-Defense gets 20%, Repair Drone gets 20%).

Does the player actively choose which weapons they fire and when, or do weapons fire automatically? (Yes, this is very relevant for the answer I have in mind)

And what's the main gameplay focus of the game? Is it more of an action-based shooting game or more of a strategic resource management game?

@Philipp Weapons can be activated and fire on their own, targets can also be selected. Turrets behave differently, when activated they automatically acquire targets and prefer split fire, but they can have focus fire targets. The game's focus is about fighting, gathering loot, exploration, mining resources, crafting, upgrading/building stations, trading, transportation. Combat is a common occurrence and every player is capable to fight, and enemies generally come in waves, however avoiding combat, fleeing and trying to survive are part of it too.

@Battle I added that information to the question and retracted my close-vote.

In reality, troops generally get the same number of rounds. As the losses mount, they may scrounge ammo from others. And there is always the ammo / reserve train. You have "runners" that retrieve and re-supply. Artillery wagons have a set number of rounds per "type" of round: solid shot; shell; etc. It's all according to "regulations". Offer a "standard army" option to avoid too much (initial) micro managing. In terms of firing rates: there's slow (3 rpm); common (6); rapid (12); magazine (40); gatling; etc. At x rounds per minute; and firing for y minutes; you can calculate consumption.

As a small info: I decided to go with the first option, whereas the player can choose the amount of extra "ammo types", which reduce maximum ammo storage. Having a higher attribute for ammo increases both the ammo capacity and reduces the cost of extra ammo types.

@GerrySchmitz What does any of this have to do with this question? 1. We are talking about scifi space ship logistics, not infantry logistics. 2. reality is a bad game designer.

Sorry. I tend to revert to historical accuracy. I found that "history" made me understand why certain tactics evolved as they did; and why "reality" seems to stop being boring at about 8x. And the concept of "infinite ammo" and "spawning" is not that fun compared to managing finite resources after all.

As Sid Meier once said:

A good game is a series of interesting choices.

That means that if you want to let the player make the choice what ammo to acquire and use in combat, then you need to make sure that this decision is interesting.
In order for a choice to be interesting, the choice must have an impact on the game, the player needs some information to predict the outcome of their decision, but not so much information that the ideal choice becomes obvious.
If you perfectly balance all the weapons and their ammo consumption, then every weapon would always do the same amount of damage per unit of ammo fired. In that case, The ideal choice is to simply make sure that no gun runs out of ammo before the others do. Not an interesting choice. So you can just as well make ammo a single resource, thus preventing unnecessary busy-work for both you and the player.
However, if you made the choice which gun to use when more interesting, that might change:

Some guns might have a better cost/benefit ratio. Some guns might do little damage, but their ammo is dirt-cheap. Some guns might be more powerful, but their ammo is a lot more expensive per point of damage inflicted, so it's more expensive to use. So the player can evaluate the difficulty of each combat encounter and then make a choice which guns to use to minimize the cost it will take them to beat it.
Some guns might be more or less effective based on the type of enemy or the combat situation. The player might fire the less effective guns anyway and thus maximize their damage output, or only fire the most effective guns, which optimizes their cost per damage inflicted at the expense of prolonging the battle and possibly taking more damage themselves.
Damage per storage might also be a relevant consideration. Some guns might have very bulky ammo, so they burn through their supply very quickly. Not a problem if the player doesn't expect a lot of combat before the next opportunity to restock. Other guns might have very compact ammo, so they would be the better choice for a longer excursion.

More complex ammo logistics in your game mean that the player needs to make all these decisions before leaving the space dock. So in order for this decision to be interesting, the player needs some information to predict what challenges they are going to face before the next restock opportunity. But not enough information to trivialize the decision by optimizing their loadout specifically for what they know they are going to face.

Oh, and don't forget to apply the three most important techniques for evaluating if adding a game mechanic has the intended effect on for your particular game: 1. playtest, 2. playtest, 3. playtest.

To have choices being "interesting" and relevant is quite a good point. In my case, the choice of weapons and "ammo types" equipped are interesting, and also subject to progression, but the amount of ammo allocated per weapon (or ammo type) could rather become annoying. The situation of "running out of ammo for specific weapons" would make sense in a game like Doom, where alternative weapons work as well, and you are incentivized to switch weapons over time, but in my case it's akin to becoming harmless against certain types/sizes of enemies.

In DOOM you can also rely on the pistol (infinite ammo) or your fists (epic kills grant more ammo). Having a weak base attack and a looting mechanic in your game may act as a "safe net" that prevents disaster due to minor oversights ("This looks bad, but I can still do it": this is an interesting outcome) but cannot help the player against major blunders that will leave them harmless and at the mercy of enemies.
